# Regex for comma separated 3 letter words

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regex for exactly 3 letter words only, separated by commas. 3 letter words can be padded with space(at most 1 on each side)

Valid Examples:

```
ORD
JFK, LAX
ABC,DEF, GHK,REW, ASD
```

Invalid Examples:

```
ORDA
OR
ORD,
JFK, LA
```

I tried the following but couldn't get it to work.

```
^(?:[A-Z ]+,)*[A-Z ]{3} +$
```

Comment: Use `^[A-Z]{3}(?:, ?[A-Z]{3})*$`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew This also seemed to do it!

Comment: I assume you do not want to allow leading/trailing spaces and only 1 optional space after `,`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `^([ ]?[A-Z]{3}[ ]?,)*([ ]?[A-Z]{3}[ ]?)+$`

https://regex101.com/r/HFeN0D/2/

It matches at least one three letter word (with spaces), preceded by any number of words three letter words with commas after them.

Comment: this did it. Thanks! saved me from 3 hours of misery!

Comment: @Nick You're welcome! If you found this helpful remember to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted so others searching for the same problem will quickly see the solution.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "3 letter words can be padded with space(at most 1 on each side)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
^[A-Z]{3}(?:[ ]?,[ ]?[A-Z]{3})*$
```

This pattern matches an initial three letter word, followed by two more terms separated by a comma with optional spaces.

Comment: Just tried this, I think it only works when there are atleast 3 words, otherwise its failing the test. ORD and ORD, LAX shows invalid

Comment: @Nick I misread the question to think that the OP only wanted three _terms_.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the pattern: `^((:? ?[A-Z]{3} ?,)*(?: ?[A-Z]{3} ?))+$`

```js
var str = `ORD
JFK, LAX
ABC,DEF, GHK,REW, ASD

ORDA
OR
ORD,
JFK, LA`;

let result =  str.match(/^((:? ?[A-Z]{3} ?,)*(?: ?[A-Z]{3} ?))+$/gm);
document.getElementById('match').innerHTML = result.join('<br>');
```

```html
<p id="match"></p>
```